# Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 3026-06-30 00:00:00

Tags: python, time-series

I have a dataframe with just one column datetime type ('Quarter').
After having done SARIMAX model with exog. variables, I want to paint the time series in a plot with the following function:

```
def eval_model(model,tr,tst,exog_tst,exog_tr,name='Model',lags=4):
    lb = np.mean(sm.stats.acorr_ljungbox(model.resid, lags=lags, return_df=True).lb_pvalue)
    pred = model.forecast(steps=len(tst))
    fig1, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(tr, label='training')
    ax.plot(tst, label='test')
    ax.plot(pred, label='prediction')
    plt.legend(loc='upper left')
    tit = name + ":  LjungBox p-value --> " + str(lb) + "\n MAPE: " + str(round(mean_absolute_percentage_error(tst, pred)*100,2)) + "%"
    plt.title(tit)
    plt.ylabel('Pasajeros')
    plt.xlabel('Date')
    plt.show()
    print(lb)

eval_model(model,tr,tst,exog_tr=exog_tr, exog_tst=exog_tst, name='Model',lags=4)
```

I got this error from Python: `Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 3026-06-30 00:00:00`

I've checked up the only datatime column ('Quarter') and I am not able to find the error. Here you can see the unique values of this column:

[image]

I also used errors='coerce' once I've trasformed the date as datetime type, but didn't work.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Please always include the complete error traceback when you get an error, and format it -as well as your code - as code.

Comment: 3026-06-30: that's when the Maya calendar (this time for real) ends. So any date after that is out of bounds because it doesn't exist.

Comment: Which part of the code is complaining about the date being `Out of bounds`. Because I checked both `datetime.datetime` and `astropy.time.Time` can handle larger values.

Answer (score 0):

So the link you provided us with the timestamps in the datetime column of your dataframe does not contain the out of range date?

With not much information about how far ahead you want to forecast, and the time intervals of the forecast... it could be possible that your model is forecasting so far into the future that it exceeds the nanosecond datetime limit of [584 years](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#timestamp-limitations) when it creates the datetime array or pandas frame you should be plotting with.